# How do I silence Siri on my HomePod mini?

Tags: siri, homepod

By default, Siri on HomePod mini comes enabled and very loud, and the minimum volume (as far as I can tell) is irritatingly loud. In fact, the whole talkback from Siri (confirming commands, etc.) is irritating and unnecessary. But I can't find how to simply shut off talkback (as I can with Siri on my iPhone).

How do I silence Siri's talkback on my HomePod mini?

Comment: I believe there have been some updates to Siri volume control on HomePod since you asked this question. The best I can offer (I don't see an option to turn off talkback) is to say "Hey Siri always speak quieter". Source: [How to change Siri volume - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209573).

Comment: @JBallin No changes in this feature have occurred since the OP. "Quieter" is not quiet enough.

Answer (score -3):

Try these:

In the Home app on your iOS or iPadOS device, touch and hold a HomePod.

Scroll down, tap the Settings button, then do any of the following:

- Deny access to [Personal Requests](https://support.apple.com/guide/homepod/setup-apd779d9bb45/1.0/homepod/1.0#apdf41297105): Tap Personal Requests, then turn off each HomePod you don't want to use Personal Requests on.
- Disable “Hey Siri” requests: Turn off Listen for “Hey Siri.”
- Disable summoning Siri using HomePod touch controls: Turn off Touch
  and Hold for Siri.
- Disable indicator light when Siri is listening: Turn off Light When
  Using Siri.
- Hear a chime when Siri is listening: Turn on Sound When Using Siri.
- Turn off VoiceOver: Tap Accessibility to access settings for
  VoiceOver and for Touch Accommodations. [See Use HomePod touch
  controls.](https://support.apple.com/guide/homepod/use-touch-controls-apd7ba1aa325/1.0/homepod/1.0)

Source: https://support.apple.com/guide/homepod/change-settings-apde6dc8093d/homepod

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Its to silence Siri. Does this not work to silence Siri?